# TableView cell selection issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift4

So I selected a cell in tableview.
it expands, shows detail text of the that cell then I started scrolling down till this selected cell goes out of view.
because of reuse identifier other cell in the the view get some the property of the selected cell automatically.

Is there any way to handle this ?

```
var selectedIndex = -1

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.labelViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60
        self.labelLeadingConstraint.constant = 136
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        selectedIndex = -1
            print("deselect")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {

            cell.secondView.isHidden = true
            cell.firstView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 0.8588, green: 0.84705, blue: 0.8745, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    } else {
        cell.secondView.isHidden = false
    }
        self.expandTableView.beginUpdates()
        //self.expandTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic )
        self.expandTableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

And i have deselect tableview function as

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPathaddres  , animated: true)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? customCell {
            cell.firstView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 0.8588, green: 0.84705, blue: 0.8745, alpha: 1.0)
            print("deselected row")
        }
    }
```

I have already disabled multiple selection.

I am attaching the 2 screenshot.
I 1 is select first cell of tableview then scroll down  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZlya_eVVjDzj02GKV9h0qJU8F29xMin/view?usp=drivesdk     once that cell goes out of scope.
Jump server 3 (as seen in this screenshot gets selected)      https://drive.google.com/file/d/15k4gLUPkgB6jGZ7AWR6km0Jajst9KKxM/view?usp=drivesdk  get selected

Comment: reset your cell in `prepareForReuse` method of the cell. Maintain the animated state information and set it only when needed in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @Sunny you can reset cell in cellForRowAt delegate as you are setting on didDeselectRowAt delegate.

Comment: but this will also reset selected cell layout

Comment: so you have to reset cell layout in cellForRowAt for selected cell

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich How should i layout in cellForRowAt for selected cell. Can you please share a code snippet.

Comment: @Sunny I gave answer to a similar question please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753084/textlabel-colour-automatically-changed-when-i-scroll-uitableview/52753623#52753623

Answer (score 2):

Since tableview reuses its cells, you need to do some extra checks if you want your one cell to be different from the others.

1. Reset the cell to its default in `prepareForReuse` method. Like
   hiding your view and reset the arrow direction in your case.
2. Check for selected index in your `cellForRow` method and expand your view like you do in your `didSelectRow` method and hide it if its not selected just as you do in your `didDeselect` method.

Comment: I implemented prepareForReuse method.                                                     
   override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        firstView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 0.8588, green: 0.84705, blue: 0.8745, alpha: 1.0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.secondView.isHidden = true  // second view is detail of cell
            self.arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "dropdown")
        }
    }

Comment: But the thing is this , when i tap a cell (second view comes up) , and scroll down till this cell goes out of view, it hides the second view of cell. but when i sroll back , i want that second view back present at that same cell.   How can i implement that ???

Comment: For this you need to check if a cell is already selected or not in your cellForRow method and if its selected, you need to show its view just like you do when its selected in your didSelect method.