# TextLabel colour automatically changed when i Scroll UiTableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textlabel

I changing textlabel color on `didSelectRowAt` but when I scroll `UITableView` it also effects in other `textlabel` also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


    if (cell.LBLIntrest.textColor == (UIColor.black))
    {
         cell.LBLIntrest.textColor = Uicolor.blue
    } else {
          cell.LBLIntrest.textColor = Uicolor.black
    }
}
```

Comment: this is occurring because when you scroll UITableView, cells dequeue and reused by tableView. so you have to reset color of that cell back to initial color in cellForRowAt delegate

Comment: I also added an answers please check.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich yup bro its work thanks man but what about multiple selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create property to hold selected cell like below

```
/* To hold selected cell */
var selectedIndexPath :IndexPath?
```

After that set color of selected cell in **cellForRowAt**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Row Number: \(indexPath.row)"

        /* Check if cell is selected then set layout accourding to your requirements */
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .blue
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
        }
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

After this manage when user select a cell in **didSelectRowAt**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Toggle if user seleted same cell
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            /* Check and toggle selected cell color */
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = cell.textLabel?.textColor == .black ? .blue : .black
        }
    } else {
        /* set color of seleted cell */
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .blue
        }
    }

    /* Save which cell is selected */
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

And last manage **didDeselectRowAt**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    /* Remove if deselect same cell */
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        selectedIndexPath = nil
    }
     /* Change color to black */
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    }
}
```

This code is for on cell selection at one time so you have to set

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    setSelectedColor(cell: cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    ...

    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        setSelectedColor(cell: cell)
    }

    return cell
}


func setSelectedColor(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    if (cell.LBLIntrest.textColor == (UIColor.black)) {
        cell.LBLIntrest.textColor = Uicolor.blue
    } else {
        cell.LBLIntrest.textColor = Uicolor.black
    }    
}
```

But, I would recommend moving that `cell.LBLIntrest.textColor = Uicolor.blue` to `UITableViewCell` under `func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` method

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // label textColor logic goes here
        // make use of selected
    }
}
```